# Can you gain health besides drinking a health potion?

Tags: torchlight-2

In World of Warcraft, you can sit and it allows the character to gain health faster. Is there anything like that in Torchlight 2?

Answer (score 10):

There are no passive, out-of-combat health regeneration (w/o skills) like in WoW.

Instead there are many other ways to generate/recover health.

You can gain health from:

- Armor and weapons with Life Steal (X Health Stolen per Hit) or Health Regen (+X Health Per Second) item mod. There is also the rare item modifier - Fully Heal Self.
- Use an Active skills such as the Engineer's Healing Bot, the
  Embermage's Death's Bounty, the Outlander's Stone Pact, Berserker's Shadow 
  Burst. There are also passive skills that can heal your character, like the 
  Engineer's Charge Reconstitution and the Berserker's Blood Hunger.
- Equip and use spell scrolls, such as Heal Self, Heal All, or Draining Touch. Pets can learn spells, too! The have 4 slots just like you character (I personally prefer to give it summon spells). It frees up some of hot bar slots and mana. (Thanks Dycker)
- Pet items can also have the modifier "X Health steal to master on Hit"

Comment: You might want to add that your pet can learn spells too, like heal all. This frees up our mana and doesn't take a spot on your hot bar. Also the Outlander ability; Stone Pact, recovers X health for 3 seconds. Also there are some pet items that have "on hit: master recovers X health"

Comment: Are there still health shrines?

Comment: @Arkive Yep, I've seen a couple.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Certain enchanted items provide health regeneration benefits.

Also, the engineer class has the Healing Bot first-level skill. This summons a small robot that heals both you and your fellow party members.

Comment: I use the Shadow Burst skill on my Berzerker to get health back, and I would guess there are probably many other skills that return health to the user as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are other ways besides health potions to gain HP, but

No, there is no bonus regeneration for being "out of combat" like WoW, and nothing like WoW's food that refills your health slowly for a lower price.